# Catch test framework issue: cannot use Catch::Session()

Tags: c++, session, testing, frameworks, catch-unit-test

I get this error in a C++ file where I am writing some tests:

```
error: no member named 'Session' in namespace 'Catch'
        testResult = Catch::Session().run(test_argc, test_argv);
                     ~~~~~~~^
```

Looking at the catch.hpp single header file, I noticed that the code that should implement the Session() member function is greyed out, probably because of an #ifdef somewhere, which I cannot find.

Is there any macro to set to use the Session class?

Catch versions: 1.5.3 and 1.5.6.

Reference: https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md

Comment: obligatory sanity check: you *are* defining `CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER` before you `#include` catch.hpp, right?

Comment: @jaggedSpire - Yes, just once, in the file where I define main(), which is not the one where I write the tests.

Comment: and the compilation error is in the file where you define main(), correct?

Comment: No, it is in the file where I call Catch::Session().

Comment: It doesn't look like you're supposed to call `Catch::Session()` outside of the file where you're defining your own main, or even construct it. The documentation explicitly says there should only ever be once instance of it: "`Catch::Session session; // There must be exactly once instance`" Presumably, preventing it from being defined in non-main files is meant to prevent violation of that requirement.

Comment: You are right. I called it just once, but in a different file. Now it works. If you write it as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you!

Comment: Done. Would you mind editing your question to include the information about where you were attempting to access `Catch::Session`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're attempting to call the constructor of `Catch::Session` from a file where you're not defining your own `main` to execute. According to the [documentation on defining your own main](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch/blob/master/docs/own-main.md), there is supposed to be only one instance of `Catch::Session`:

```
Catch::Session session; // There must be exactly once instance
```

It's likely Catch is preventing construction of `Catch::Session` in translation units where it can't be used in a custom `main` definition (since that's where it's supposed to be used), to prevent exactly the mistake you've made from compiling.

Comment: and what if I want to run tests multiple times per one application run, with different argc, how can ones do that, without using only one instance, that seems to be keeping arguments..

Comment: sounds like new question material to me.

Answer (score 2):

Reference to https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/own-main.md

You can only provide main in the same file you defined CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER.

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_RUNNER
#include "catch.hpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
  // global setup...

  int result = Catch::Session().run( argc, argv );

  // global clean-up...

  return result;
}
```